# Debugging JavaScript: Live profiling?

Tags: javascript, profiling, real-time

Let's say I have a web site with some JavaScript.

While I'm using/navigating around the site, I'd like all the JavaScript functions that execute to have their names logged to the console.

In other words, if I, for example, have a function named `refreshGrid` that executes when I click on a button, I want to see `refreshGrid()` appear in the console, live.

Don't get caught up on this example though--I'm looking for a way to log every single function that executes, *when it executes*, like you see in the the Firebug or Chrome profilers—but *live*, in real-time.

I found a great(?) suggestion (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921966/live-javascript-debugging-by-recording-function-calls-and-parameters) here on SO, but there's no example.

Comment: not all functions have names, and some are called via aliases, how do you expect to log those?

Comment: What are you trying to find with this kind of debugging ?

Comment: Remind me and I'll have a go later at this, I think I know what would work.

Answer (score 0):

IE (which I am not a big fan of) has Developer Tools.  When activated, you can select the Profiler tab.  You get information like this:

[image]