# logging function calls in javascript

Tags: javascript, v8

Is it possible to log into console name of the just fired function (possible with its parameters);

I'm asking about V8 engine, maybe there is a plugin to chrome dev tools, or any of firefox plugins could to that.

Comment: Have you tried using Profiler?

Comment: i think this question is possible a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921966/live-javascript-debugging-by-recording-function-calls-and-parameters