# Profile Javascript function on live code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a web scraping newbie. I have identified a JS function on a server, whose I/O I need to track. It's an obscured encryption function, and I need to know what values it takes for input and what it outputs. How can I get this done?

So far, I've opened up the web page in firebug, identified where the function is called and then set a breakpoint. However, when I refresh the page and clear my cache, the browser ignores my breakpoint and loads the page as if there were no breakpoints on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.log` in your function to load data to console. But it's better to use it any debug state:

```
if (app.debug) {
   console.log(data)
}
```

Where `app` for example is your namespace, `debug` is flag for logging and `data` is your function/application data.

More info about [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console).

About clear cache: Firebug and Chrome Dev Tools remove all breakpoints from file if file was changed.

Comment: I am a bit confused when you mention namespace. The page I'm working on is'nt mine. All I have is a listing of several functions whose call order I managed to discover. However, I cant figure what value is being passed into the function.

Comment: Can you add any code to the function? Do you have access to the function?

Comment: No I cant add any console functions to it. A similar question to mine can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921966/live-javascript-debugging-by-recording-function-calls-and-parameters

Comment: Yes, it will help you.